# Change the image links when a button is pressed

Tags: jquery, html

A user posted this question: *I have images in HTML which link to certain movie recommendations using an API. I also have a switch button on my site where I have music and movies. What I am trying to do is that when I press the switch I can change the links inside the pictures from movie to music and vice versa.*

The original question was closed. This question was created to communicate one possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do is to have two div structures, one with the movies and one with the music. One of the divs is always hidden and the button just switches which one is visible.

*Otherwise, you are getting into either (a) using forms to navigate to a different page, or (more popular these days) using AJAX to call a back-end file to send different data, and updating the page with the new data.*

Here is a simple example of how to use the button to switch out which div is visible. Note that we style each div structure as `position:absolute` so that they are on top of each other - but one is always invisible:

```js
$('#music').hide();

$('#btn').click(function(){
  if ( $(this).text() == 'music' ) {
    $(this).text('movies');
    $('#movies').fadeOut();
    $('#music').fadeIn();
  }else{
    $(this).text('music');
    $('#music').fadeOut();
    $('#movies').fadeIn();
  }
});
```

```css
div{box-sizing:border-box;}
.topclass{position:absolute;top:40px;left:0;}
.row{overflow:hidden;width:100%;}
.col1{float:left;width:20%;}
.col2{float:left;width:80%;}

#hdr{width:100%;overflow:hidden;}
  #hdr_left {float:left;width:75%;}
  #hdr_right{float:left;width:25%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hdr">
  <div id="hdr_left"></div>
  <div id="hdr_right"><button id="btn">music</button></div>
</div><!-- #hdr -->
<div id="movies" class="topclass">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col1"><img src="http://placeimg.com/100/75/animals"></div>
    <div class="col2">Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col1"><img src="http://placeimg.com/100/70/animals"></div>
    <div class="col2">Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col1"><img src="http://placeimg.com/95/75/animals"></div>
    <div class="col2">Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- #movies -->

<div id="music" class="topclass">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col1"><img src="http://placeimg.com/100/75/people"></div>
    <div class="col2">But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing of a pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col1"><img src="http://placeimg.com/100/70/people"></div>
    <div class="col2">But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing of a pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col1"><img src="http://placeimg.com/95/75/people"></div>
    <div class="col2">But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing of a pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness.
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- #music -->
```